# shell script that determines whether a parent directory contains a particular subdirectory

Tags: shell

Write a Linux shell script contains D1 D2 that determines whether D1 (immediately) contains D2, D2 (immediately) contains D1, or no such relationship exists between directories D1 and D2, There is no need to recursively examine subdirectories

Comment: I'll just give you a hint: Use `find` commands. Questions like these are to test your understanding of the course from which you got this question. You should atleast give a try. If yes, then update your question here with what all did you do, and where you got stuck.

Comment: I tried using find like this, "find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l". It only counts the number of subdirectories (unrecursively) of the specified parent directory ($1 argument). I don't know how to insert $2 argument (the subdirectory I am comparing with) in this shell command so that I can compare if this subdirectory is really related (or exist) from the parent directory ($1 argument I specified). Thank you

Comment: The question might be as simple as 'does `"$D1/$D2"` exist as a directory or does `"$D2/$D1"` exist as a directory?'  Or it might be more convoluted, asking 'is `$D1` a prefix of `$D2` or is `$D2` a prefix of `$D1`?'  Or it might be something else altogether.